# Lightweight replacement for Spring IoC - potentially for targetting Android devices

Tags: java, android, spring, inversion-of-control

I'm currently searching for replacement for Spring IoC container. I like Spring, but it is very heavy (jars size) even if I use only core features. This is painful for WAR applications, and absolutely unacceptable for Android devices.

So this is what I need:

1. The most basic use: IoC only, so this xml-or-so configuration file in which I declare what where to inject. This would be used in Android devices.
2. More advanced use. Transaction managemenet included. JDBC helpers included. For use in web/stand-alone applications, but not on android.

I've found [tapioca](http://code.google.com/p/tapioca/), but as I see, it is a new project and not widely-used, so I'm afraid it would be buggy, not very functional and soon abandoned.

So, do you have any (at best good) experience with replacing Spring with lighter IoC container and could recommend me something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)? There's a version for Android called [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I've looked, but I've forgotted to add that annotation-based injection is unpreferred option because of its lack of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I use RoboGuice 2.0 in all my projects. It's very simple to use, and very powerfull. 2.0 supports fragments. There's a number of Guice tools that you can use also, like AssistedInject to allow injection of classes that need arguments in their constructor, and Multibinder that allows you to bind multiple implementations to one interface.
RoboGuice does not support aop, unfortunately.